# Show and hide a button of the videojs player after a few seconds that the video has started without pressing or clicking on a button (Javascript only)

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a button like "Ignore recap" of Netflix.

I create a player with videojs. And I created a button to make the user ignore the credits of the video.

1. First he can click on the button and the video goes forward a few seconds until the end of the credits. And when he clicks the button should be hidden.
2. Secondly, when the user does not press any button, the button should be visible until the end of the credits or recap. Then it should disappear. I want a help please on javascript code only for this second option; Not Jquery.

```js
var player = videojs("videojs-sprite-thumbnails-player");

// First option The user click the button and ignore the recap - The time of the recap is 30 seconds.
ignoreButtonDom.onclick = function st(){
 player.currentTime(30);
 var divsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName("vjs-st-button");
  for(var i = 0; i < divsToHide.length; i++)
    {
    divsToHide[i].style.display="none";
    }
};

// For the second option I don't have I need help.
```

Comment: So what _exactly_ do you need help with then? Where and how did you try to implement this, and what problems did you run into?

Comment: I solved the first problem, the one where I click on the "Ignore introduction" button.
Now I need help with the second problem where if I don't click the button and the seconds or credits time is up, the button needs to disappear.

Thanks @CBroe

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).